# Draw pie chart and rotate it

Tags: java, graphics, rotateanimation

Write an application with a pie chart control (look at the picture below). The pie chart can be rotated in all directions using mouse, colors are filled randomly, number of sections can vary. No any 3D library can be used for drawing.
[image]

here is my code what is wrong, I can't rotate in 3d.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Slice{

    private double value;
    private  Color color;
    public Slice(double _value){
        Random numGen = new Random();
        int R =  numGen.nextInt(256);
        int G = numGen.nextInt(256);
        int B = numGen.nextInt(256);
        this.setColor(new Color(R,G,B));
        this.value = _value;    
    }
    public void setColor(Color _color){
        this.color = _color;
    }
    public double getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }
}

class panel extends JPanel{
    JButton bt;
    JTextField txt;
    public panel() {
        bt = new JButton("Submit");
        txt = new JTextField(5);
        add(txt);
        add(bt);
    }   

}

class Component extends JComponent {

    int movx = 0;
    int movy = 0;
    private double angle = 0;
    private double radius = 0.0D;
    private  Random numGen;
    private int w = 500;
    private int h = 500;



    Slice[] slice ;
    public Component(double[] a, int size){
        slice = new Slice[size];
        for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ){
            slice[i] = new Slice(a[i]);
        }
        numGen = new Random();
        Listener listener = new Listener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);



    }

    class Listener extends MouseAdapter{
        private double LastAngle;
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            LastAngle = getAngle(e.getPoint());
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            double curAngle = getAngle(e.getPoint());
            double deltaAngle = curAngle - LastAngle;
            angle += deltaAngle;
            repaint();
            LastAngle = curAngle;
        }
        private double getAngle(Point point) {
            double x = point.getX() - 0.5 * w;
            double y = point.getY() - 0.5 * h;
            return Math.atan2(y, x);
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      // g2.translate(250, 250);
        g2.rotate(angle,(w/2),(h/2));
        drawPie(g2, getBounds(), slice);

    }
    public void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, Slice[] s){
        double total = 0.0D;

        //calculate total value
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
            total+=s[i].getValue();

        radius = total/2*Math.PI;
        double curentValue = 0.0D;
        int startAngle = 0; 
        //for(int j=10;j>0;j--){
        for(int i = 0;i<s.length;i++){           
            //s[i].setColor(new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256)));
            startAngle = (int)((curentValue*360)/total);
            int arcAngle = (int)((s[i].getValue()*360)/total) ;
            g.setColor(s[i].getColor());
            //g.rotate(angle);//row AA 

            g.setComposite ( AlphaComposite.getInstance ( AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f ) );

            g.fillArc(0, 0, w, h, startAngle, arcAngle);   



        curentValue+=s[i].getValue();}

        //}
    }


}

public class PieChart {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();      
        frame.setSize(600,600);       
        int size;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a[];
        System.out.println("enter size:");
        size = s.nextInt();
        a = new double [size];
        System.out.println("enter array of value:");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            a[i] = s.nextDouble();
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(new Component(a,size));        
        frame.setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Have you tried using mouse events to change the starting angle?

Comment: Now I draw pie chart, but i would like to rotate it the folowing way: When I move mouse up chart rotate 3d, but i can't use 3d library. and how can I draw chart like as in picture

Comment: You don't need a 3D library.  Your chart starts at a particular angle, you can add control(s) to change this from 0 degrees to some other angle.